# How to derive the geodesic equation in general relativity from the relativistic Euler equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curvature, general-relativity

The energy-momentum tensor of a perfect fluid is $$T_{\mu\nu}=(p+\rho)u_\mu u_\nu + pg_{\mu\nu}$$
The local conservation of energy and momentum is expressed by the equation
$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=(p+\rho)u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu+g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu p+u^\nu\left[\nabla_\mu(p+\rho)u^\mu\right]=0$$

By contracting with the projection tensor $h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}+u_\mu u_\nu$, we can obtain the **relativistic Euler equation** 
$$(p+\rho)u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu + (g^{\mu\nu}+u^\mu u^\nu)\partial_\mu p=0$$

This is the equation of motion for fluid flows in a background metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.
On the other hand, the motion of particles is governed by the geodesic equation.

**Since hydrodynamics is the continuum limit of particle dynamics, is it possible to derive the geodesic equation from the relativistic Euler equation as a limiting case?**

Answer (score 1):

The "particles" in a relativistic prefect fluid do not necessarily follow geodesics; the pressure essentially arises from short-ranged interactions between the particles. Another way of seeing this is that the nonrelativistic limit is a classical ideal fluid, which certainly does not always flow in straight lines.

If pressure is zero, however (i.e. "perfect dust"), then particles *do* follow geodesics. Is it evident from the relativistic Euler equation you have written that this is the case?

(recall the form of the geodesic equation $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}=0$)